# connecting to the database engine in Microsoft SQL Server 2005

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I had to connect my netbeans application to Microsoft SQL Server 2005 so that I am able to read the data back to application (after I store it !) . But I haven't  been able to create a table yet since I am able to connect to the database engine as it says.

How do I connect to the database engine in Microsoft SQL Server 2005 ? This is what it currently displays when I open *Microsoft Server SQL Management Studio* :

[image]

and this is the SQL Server Configuration Manager :

[image]

Now what do I do to connect to the database engine ?

*Note : Please let me know if I need to add some more information*

Answer (score 1):

You create tables through your management studio through `File -> New -> Database Engine Query` and provide the server name, user name and password. This will open an SQL editor where you can `USE <your DB>` and start creating tables.

You can also register your DB server to avoid entering the authentication details every time, in the management studio. Once you register your server, test the connection, you can open it in Object Explorer or open a Query window directly etc.,

To connect to this database from a Java program, you need Microsoft SQL JDBC driver (jTDS is also a good JDBC driver for SQL server) and a  tutorial on how to use Java JDBC API to connect to SQL server from Java programs.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: and how do I set the server name,username and password ?

Comment: server name is the machine where the SQL server is running, and the user credentials are those created by you or whoever has installed the server and created users. If you are not the one who installed it, you should contact your DBA for the credentials to be used to use the database. If the server is set up to use domain credentials, then select "Windows Authentication" from that dropdown.

Comment: what do you mean by domain credentials ?

Comment: I have installed a fresh copy of sql server 2005. [This is the first screen as I open sql server 2005 management studio](http://i48.tinypic.com/10oliec.jpg) while installing it didn't ask me anything except the password. Still I am unable to connect. what is **sa**,is it automatically set the username ? and USER-PC what is it ? It was the old name of my pc

Comment: @Y.E.P, Did you get to connect to the server?

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the Database Engine and click "connect". You will need to supply the IP address (or Server Name) of the SQL Server you wish to connect to. Choose SQL Server Authentication (unless you environment supports Windows Authentication) and enter your password.  No password is requried if using Windows Authentication.

HTH

Comment: I right click database engine to find `connect` is disabled. I guess I am missing some prerequisites

Comment: Are you using the SQL Management Studio Express - the free download?

Comment: I have installed a fresh copy of sql server 2005. [This is the first screen as I open sql server 2005 management studio](http://i48.tinypic.com/10oliec.jpg) while installing it didn't ask me anything except the password. Still I am unable to connect. what is **sa**,is it automatically set the username ? and USER-PC what is it ? It was the old name of my pc

Comment: "sa" is the default System Administrator account. I believe you can just press enter without typing a password to gain access. Note that the SQL Server 2008 Express is also a free download.